# Using quiver with two dimensional array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, plot

---

I have two dimensional array of x,y. The first row is x and the second row is y.
I am trying to use quiver on that array but with no success.

If someone knows how to plot, it will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: For quiver, you need start and end point of the arrow. Where are the start/end points in your array? Is point 1 a start and point 2 an end, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for ?

Define a 2D array (each column represents the components [image]
of the vector [image] )

```
MyArray = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
```

Extract the coordinates of the 4 vectors:

```
u = MyArray(1,:);
v = MyArray(2,:);
```

Define the origin as a starting point for the 4 vectors:

```
x = zeros(1,4);
y = zeros(1,4);
```

And finally call the `quiver` function for 2D vectors:

```
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```